# F# WPF events: "Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression"

Tags: wpf, f#, f#-3.0

This is driving me nuts. I am looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233229.aspx) at Microsoft's function examples.
I can't see what I am doing wrong.

So, I am trying to use F# with WPF, I found a working online project template for it.  [Here it is](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e0907c99-bb04-4eb8-9692-9333d5ff4399) .I was about to get started. Unfortunately, the designer does not work for generating events in the F# code by double clicking an element like it does in C#. But oh well, I can set what the Click does anyway. I decided I would do it all manually.

Here is my flawed attempt:

```
module MainApp

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open FSharpx

let mutable doc = ""

type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

let loadWindow() =
   let window = MainWindow()

   // Your awesome code code here and you have strongly typed access to the XAML via "window"

   window.Root

   let make (sender:Object, e:RoutedEventArgs) =
    doc<- doc +"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
    0


[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

In any event, It does not like the line with let make on it. It gives me this error:

```
Block following this 'let' is unfinished. Expect an expression
```

And yet, clearly I read on the MSDN

```
  The compiler uses the final expression in a function body to determine the return value and type
```

So, it has a return, how is it an unfinished expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are supposed to return `window.Root` from `loadWindow`.  Right now the last bit of code inside `loadWindow` is the declaration of a `make` function, which is not valid.  Remember, indentation determines scope in F#.

If you wanted to add a new function `make`, but leave the body of `loadWindow` basically empty, you need to align the indentation properly:

```
let loadWindow() =
   let window = MainWindow()

   // Your awesome code code here and you have strongly typed access to the XAML via "window"

   window.Root

let make (sender:Object, e:RoutedEventArgs) =
    doc<- doc +"<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
    0
```